# C#にてActionを返す非同期メソッドをasyncメソッドでラップしたい

Tags: c#

`.Net Framework 4.6.1`以降のC#にて、戻り値が`void`で引数に`Action`を使う非同期処理用のメソッドに対してasync/awaitを適用する方法はあるのでしょうか？

下記のサンプルコードにおける`ReadSQLWrapper`メソッドのように、`Action`で戻ってきた値をラムダ式の外側で取得して、非同期実行の戻り値として返せることが理想です。

サンプルコード修正の前提条件として`DBManagerMock`自体は改修できないものとさせてください。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Execute();
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            var sqls = new string[] { "select hoge;", "select fuga;", "select piyo;" };
            //理想のコード
            var tasks = sqls.Select(ReadSQLWrapper).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);    //Taskなら同期実行も非同期実行も思うがまま
            tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }

        //懸案となる、うまく動作しないasyncの疑似メソッド
        private async Task<string> ReadSQLWrapper(string sql)
        {
            var db = new DBManagerMock();
            string result = "ダミーの初期化子"; //DBManagerMockのReadSQLメソッドのActionを返したい
            //await db.ReadSQL(sql, r => { result = r; }); //エラー CS4008  'void' を待機することができません
            return result;
        }
    }

    //このクラスは改修不可
    public class DBManagerMock
    {
        public void ReadSQL(string sql, Action<string> result)
        {
            //非同期でDB接続して結果を返す
            result(string.Format("{0}の実行結果", sql));
        }
    }
}
```

`AutoResetEvent`でも理想に近いコーディングは可能ですが、非同期実行時の[実行待ち件数の上限がある](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2702545)ため、`async Task`を返す方がより利便性が高いと期待しています。

そもそもasync/awaitの理解に問題があるようでしたらご指摘いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPL以外の非同期処理をブリッジしたい場合は`TaskCompletionSource<T>`で`Task<T>`を作成するとタスクの状態を明示的に制御できます。

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
new DBManagerMock().ReadSQL(tcs.SetResult);
return tcs.Task;
```

なお例外が発生した場合には`SetException`を呼び出すなどの考慮が必要ですが、元のAPIでの扱いが不明なので無視しています。

Comment: 実際のコードでは、DB接続クラスで例外を吸収するため例外は考慮しませんでしたが、`SetException`を使用して例外処理も可能なことを確認しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

@pgrho さんの回答を元にTaskCompletionSourceで非同期処理をブリッジし、例外処理を追加してみました。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Execute();
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            var sqls = new string[] { "select hoge;", "select fuga;", "select piyo;", null };
            var tasks = sqls.Select(ReadSQLWrapper).ToArray();
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);    //Taskなら同期実行も非同期実行も思うがまま
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle(e =>
                {
                    return (e is FormatException);  //不正なSQLがあっても処理を続行する
                });
            }
            //Where文で、ハンドル済みのエラーを除外
            tasks.Where(t => !t.IsFaulted).Select(t => t.Result).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }

        private Task<string> ReadSQLWrapper(string sql)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            try
            {
                new DBManagerMock().ReadSQL(sql, tcs.SetResult);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //try-catchで例外処理
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    public class DBManagerMock
    {
        public void ReadSQL(string sql, Action<string> result)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql)) throw new FormatException("不正なSQLです"); //空文字は不正なSQLとして例外を返す
            //非同期でDB接続して結果を返す
            result(string.Format("{0}の実行結果", sql));
        }
    }
}
```